How can you catch keyboard input in an Delphi Linux application without ReadLn?
I am using RAD Studio 12 to develop a Delphi console application for Linux, and I would like to be able to catch keyboard input but without waiting for Enter to be pressed.
The behavior is similar to applications such as top and many others.
In a regular Windows console application, all required function calls could be found in the Winapi.Windows unit.
It had advanced console functions such as ReadConsoleInput(), GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() and SetConsoleTextAttribute(). These allows the program to catch events from the console such as key presses and window focus, and add the ability to change the text and background color of the console.
In Lazarus, which is Pascal as well, there is the crt unit with all required functions.
But for Linux application development in Delphi, I cannot find any straight-forward way to really do anything more in the console than ReadLn() and WriteLn(), and few other minor elements.
So, is there a way in Delphi to read/catch these events, and find alternatives for the Winapi.Windows functions, for Linux?

Decades ago, the CRT unit in Turbo Pascal provided this functionality. There are various re-implementations in modern Pascal/Delphi for it. For example a Windows version: http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/console.html

FreePascal has KeyPressed function. Since it tries to be compatible with Delphi, then it might have it too. Since I had no access to Delphi: uses Crt; begin repeat until KeyPressed; end. source: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/keypressed.html

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly there is no crt unit or KeyPressed() function in Delphi. FreePascal has Delphi compatibility, but it also has a lot of things that Delphi doesn't have.

I know @RemyLebeau, If Delphi has no crt unit, here you can find minimal delphi crt unit implements KeyPressed: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1638153

@Brian The Velthuis.AnsiConsole library is certainly a start. It has support for text formatting like Color and Background color. But unfortunately, no way to check if a key is pressed...

Outside of reading (which would be readln) from stdin, you might be able to use curses/ncurses. They are typically available in C, I don't know how you'd go about linking them to Delphi Linux (something similar to the way you'd do it in Delphi Windows, I image)
